# Selenium wait until textbox value change

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I came across a situation, on selecting combobox value textbox value changes. I need to wait until textbox change to a particular value. I have tried wait.Until, please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Use the Webdriver built in wait logic - ExplicitWait.   http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: Have you tried using the following logic?
`public static WebDriverWait webDriverWait = null; 
 webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 480);
  webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath("textbox xpath"), "text for which you are waiting"));

 `

Answer (score 0):

If you already knows the value, which going to reflect in the text box after the combo box change. Then you could create a xPath like.

//*[contains(text(),'Expectedvalue']

Then create a method for checking whether that xPath is available or not.

```
 public boolean isElementPresent(String xPath)` 
 { 
    try
    {
       this.driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath);
       return true;
     } 
       catch()
      {
        return false;
      }
  }
```

Then you can check using while loop

```
`//Do the code for changing combo box value
  while(isElementPresent("//*[contains(text(),'Expectedvalue']")
 {//do the necessary actions}`
```

Answer (score 0):

//Assume the Combo box is edited also the Text box is visible

```
while(! driver.findElement(By.xpath("textboxXpath")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("expected value"))
{
   System.out.println("waiting for text to be loaded");
}
```

end of this loop, the text box must be loaded with expected value
**Caution:**
This may lead you to infinite execution. implement with a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(! driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_combo_box")).getAttribute("value").equals("Expected Value"))
{/*Loops till value is written*/}
```

Here we loops till the value of the combo box equals expected value.